# chrome flexbox rendering causes content overflow too soon

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, overflow, flexbox

I'm using flexbox to enclose content of unknown and variable size.
In my example below, two side-by-side child boxes in one parent.

In Firefox (26.0 on Linux Mint) I can manually shrink the viewport width with no horizontal overflow. It does give a little too much width to the box with less content, but it's not a deal-breaker.

However, In Chrome (Chromium 31 on Linux Mint) the flexing of the two child boxes ('capsule's in my css) is worse, and making the viewport narrow causes horizontal overflow in the right hand panel long before it should.

I have searched and I don't think there's a relevant issue here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues .

Maybe it's not a bug in Chrome but is simply different rendering algorithms and, given other content, Chrome would out-perform Firefox.

Either way, is there something I can add to my css to make newer browsers more consistent in their behaviour?

I believe the following is a minimum working example.

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/AlanQ/668GL/

html:

```
<div id="container">

    <div class="capsule">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
    </div>

    <div class="capsule">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
    </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
div#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch; 
  flex-direction: row;
  border: solid 2px black;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 2px; }

div.capsule {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1; 

  border: solid 2px red;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 2px; }
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using Flexbox?  You get the desired behavior in Chrome if you use the table display properties instead:  http://jsfiddle.net/668GL/2/

Comment: @cimmanon In your jsfiddle example, `height: 100%;` causes the page to be too large vertically. `box-sizing: border-box;` fixes this in Chrome but not FF. But then, in Chrome not FF, the border of the inner boxes (capsules) extends below the border of the container (not in jsFiddle but in Chrome stand-alone).
Frying pan to fire methinks.

Comment: appears to be working properly with no overflow for me in Chrome 32